# Exporting const from inside default function to another file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am quite new to React, and React Native, but I would like to pass a const variable from inside a function, to another file. I have tried defining it outside of my function and then let it get modified inside my function, but I get an invalid Hook Call Error. This is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Text,
} from "react-native";

function JoinScreen({ navigation }) {
  const joinHandler = () => {
    navigation.navigate("JoinSwipeScreen");
  };

  const [code, setCode] = useState("");
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={styles.inputCode}
        placeholder="Room code..."
        onChangeText={(val) => setCode(val)}
      />
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.joinButt} onPress={joinHandler}>
        <Text style={styles.joinTxt}>Join</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}

//styles

export default JoinScreen;
```

Edit: I am trying to export the variable code to another file. Please help if you can, and ask any questions if I was unclear.

Comment: I don't get how the code you posted is related to your question. It looks valid to me, should work and doesn't reflect your question. Are you trying to pass the state outside the functional component?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment, I forgot to say that I am trying to export the variable called "code"

Comment: You can't just export the value `code` you can pass it on as a props to one of the child components. If you want to propagate the value up, you should investigate React Context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use the state of a component outside that component. `useState` should be used at the **top-level** of a functional component only, ant that prevents it from being exported in any way.

In order to share a state across components, either:

- Keep the state in a parent component, pass it down to the children via props, and notify the parent that the state should change with callbacks
- Use [contexts](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper)
- Use a third party library as state management like [Redux](https://react-redux.js.org/)

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for your answer, will investigate the best method for me. It was to my understanding that useState was the only method to grab the value of a TextInput, would you happen to know if there is another method that would then make it easier to export? Anyways, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Do you want to use it in the parent component?

Comment: I would like to use it in a different plain javascript file that would handle a backend component of the App (a connection to a DB).

Comment: Well I guess one option is to pass a function of that plain javascript file as the callback of `onChangeText`